# Shared Cloud Server MySQL Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, cloud, hosting, shared

My website suddenly stopped working yesterday.  My hosting service is telling me that my application stopped because of overloading the server.  My average monthly bandwidth is 4.5 GB and my total disk space for my database is about 700 MB.  I have around 6000 users total, but the average number of entry processes is less than 1.

My users have not suddenly started creating more transactions. In the past week my highest bandwidth was about 400 KB/min.  In a peak hour there might be 225 MB downloaded, mostly small icons embedded in my site.  I have one mysql table with around 600K entries that gets accessed a lot, but the entries are tiny and there are indexes.

Is my hosting service giving me the runaround?  Should a shared host in the cloud be able to handle this load?

[Resource Usage 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq1TX.png)[Resource Usage 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teNvq.png)

Comment: Usually when we speak about overload it means cpu overload. Do you have any information concerning cpu load?

Comment: *"Should a shared host in the cloud be able to handle this load?*"  Maybe.  But those numbers alone aren't meaninful, so this is not a question that anybody but the shared hosting provider can answer, and probably not even they can, without more info.  The likely issue is that your site is doing something you don't expect or yet understand, but that isn't something we can help you with unless you have something specifics to report, and even then the question -- with more specific detail -- probably belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: I added images of the resource usage from cpanel for the last 7 days.  Note that the big spikes are during the middle of the night - presumably the service provider is doing backups?